# Unreachable code detected. Why?

Tags: c#

Im trying to learn c# by reading Herbert Schildt "c# 4.0 the complete reference" and in one of examples I have this warning CS0162 Unreachable code detected and underlined Console. How to fix that and why it happened?

```
using System;
class ProdSum
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int prod;
        int sum;
        int i;
        sum = 0;
        prod = 1;
        for (i = 1; 1 <= 10; i++)
        {
           sum = sum + i;
           prod = prod * i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Summ = " + sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Prod = " + prod);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: The for loop.  Middle term should read i <= 10

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error, voting for closing.

Comment: You wrote `1 <= 10` in the for loop which is always true. Thus, the program remains forever inside the for loop and never reaches the three `Console...` lines

Comment: Sorry everyone that I bothered you.. Couldn't find this simple mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`1 <= 10` is always true, so the code that follow the for loop is never reached. You meant `i <= 10`

```
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your condition is comparing digit `1` with number `10`

```
1 <= 10
```

This expression will always be true and control will never flow out of the loop.

You probably need `i <= 10`